# formula for array max if Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

So this is my formula:

ws8.Range("Y2:Y" & lrowWFS).FormulaArray = "=Max(if(x2='New Stock Data'!H:H,'New Stock Data'!G:G))"

Problem is it's returning to {=Max(if(x2='New Stock Data'!H:H,'New Stock Data'!G:G))} in Y3 onwards.

Any idea how to solve?

Answer (score 0):

It should be as simple as to change `FormulaArray` to `Formula`. (I haven't tested this), try:

```
ws8.Range("Y2:Y" & lrowWFS).Formula = "=Max(if(x2='New Stock Data'!H:H,'New Stock Data'!G:G))"
```

Comment: But how to I turn it into an array?

Comment: This will work only in Excel 365 and it requires `.Formula2`, e.g. `ws8.Range("Y2:Y" & lrowWFS).Formula2 = "=MAX(IF('New Stock Data'!H:H=X2,'New Stock Data'!G:G))"`. But that would be silly. In Excel 365, he could simply use: `ws8.Range("Y2:Y" & lrowWFS).Formula = "=MAXIFS('New Stock Data'!G:G,'New Stock Data'!H:H,X2)"`

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things. The generic formula looks like this: `{=MAX(IF(criteria_range=criteria,value_range))}`. So, instead of `x2='New Stock Data'!H:H`, you want to use: `'New Stock Data'!H:H=x2`. Other than that, unlike regular formulas, array formulas assigned to a range do not adjust relative cell references.

E.g. `Range("A1:A2").Formula = "=B1"` will successively lead to `=B1` and `=B2`, while `Range("A1:A2").FormulaArray = "=B1"` will lead to 2x `=B1`.

One solution is to loop through your range and assign the array formulas to each cell individually. E.g.

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim lrowWFS As Long

lrowWFS = 3

Set rng = ws8.Range("Y2:Y" & lrowWFS)

For Each cell In rng
    cell.FormulaArray = "=MAX(IF('New Stock Data'!H:H=" & Cells(cell.Row, "X").Address(False, False) & ",'New Stock Data'!G:G))"
Next cell
```

A better solution would be to use `SUMPRODUCT` instead. This avoids the use of an array formula, and thus also the need for a loop.

E.g.:

```
With rng
    .Formula = "=SUMPRODUCT(MAX(('New Stock Data'!H:H=X2)*('New Stock Data'!G:G)))"
End With
```

More in general, I would advise proper specification of the ranges in the formula. Define `first_row` and `last_row` and use something like this:

`"=SUMPRODUCT(MAX(('New Stock Data'!H$" & first_row & ":H$" & last_row & "=X2)*('New Stock Data'!G$" & first_row & ":G$" & last_row & ")))"`